# Ricoh SP111 printer setup help

Tags: printing, ricoh

I heard this printer would work on Ubuntu, but I'm having problems.

I dont even know how to execute the "check requirements" script.

Answer (score 11):

To install the printer in Ubuntu, first you need to install a couple of dependencies:

1. Install `pbmtojbg` and `inotify-wait`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install jbigkit-bin inotify-tools
   ```
2. Now download the cups driver:

   ```
   git clone git@github.com:droidzone/ricoh-sp100.git
   ```
3. Copy the file `pstoricohddst-gdi` to the directory containing cups filters:

   ```
   sudo cp pstoricohddst-gdi /usr/lib/cups/filter/
   sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoricohddst-gdi
   ```
4. Now open the Printers applet:

   1. *Add Printer > Choose Ricoh SP 111 > Choose PPD file*
   2. Choose `RICOH_Aficio_SP_111.ppd`

   If you're unable to select the PPD file by the above steps, try the following to add printer from the CUPS web interface:

   1. In your web browser, navigate to http://localhost:631/
   2. *CUPS for Administrators > Adding Printers and Classes
      Printers > Add a printer*
   3. Enter your root username and password
   4. When your printer is connected and switched on Ubuntu should detect it and assign it a name. Select that printer right now. Click next a couple of times until you reach the section where you're asked to select the PPD file.
   5. At this point, choose the file `RICOH_Aficio_SP_111.ppd`.

Source: [My blog](https://blog.droidzone.in/2015/09/23/install-ricoh-sp111-laser-printer-in-ubuntu/)

Comment: Worked like a charm

Comment: This worked sweet on my Ubuntu laptop, but failed on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: PPA with deb pakage `ricoh-sp-series` https://launchpad.net/~lafricain79/+archive/ubuntu/lafricainenvrac

Comment: Worked well, any way to install in mac?

Comment: this git repo is unavailable now

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan The repo is still available.

Comment: showing page not found in github @JoelGMathew

Comment: @AjithCNarayanan It's not a website. It's a git repository. Try to clone it.

Comment: You can check the repository address included in this post, @Ajay

Comment: what after sudo apt-get update  what should I install by sudo apt-get install. As sudo apt-get install lafricainenvrac  failing.

Comment: Joel as link given in your blog is no more available. Please update the link. In my case driver available at link "https://codeload.github.com/zhangtemplar/ricoh-sp100/zip/refs/heads/master" worked like charm. Thanks

Comment: @Ajay You didnt need to visit my blog. The answer given above is complete, and has the right repo, which is my github.