# Ricoh SP 111 Printer + Stability Problems (I'm going nuts!!)

Tags: drivers, printing

First of all sorry for making a duplicate question:

[Ricoh SP111 printer setup help | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help)

However, when i try to get help on that question it said that i don't have enough reputation for making comment, i also couldn't make an answer on that page.

Anyway, i have Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop, instead of an upgrade from 16.04 i made a pure installation.I installed almost all of my programs; but i got 2 basic problems:

1) The system is unstable, as when i use web browsers it pauses momentoraily; also i have a lot of noise from hardware which is clearly screaming, just like im playing Counter-Strike style 3D games.Is it normal just because it is not completely released or is there a way i can check system stuff and fix? I think my hardware is ok:

16 GB RAM,
1 TB HD,
NVidia GForce GT940M

This is the output of the `top` command:

[image: This is the output of "top" command:]

2) My second problem is about installing the driver.First i followed these instructions: (1)

Installation instructions:

1. Copy pstoricohddst-gdi to cups' filters directory (usually /usr/lib/cups/filter).
2. Install jbigkit package (jbitkit-bin in Ubuntu)
3. Make sure it is executable by lp user.
4. Add printer through CUPS' web interface, click 'Choose file' at driver select page and select supplied .PPD file, continue to setup.

As i proceed, i stuck at step-2.I could not make changes on CUPS web interface either because of root error.It wants admin login but there is no admin-pw question when i enter "localhost:631/admin".Then i tried these instructions:

"[PrintingCupsWebInterface | Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PrintingCupsWebInterface)" (2)

Which resulted a disaster!! Now localhost denies to connect and gives an error saying "check your internet and proxy settings" bla bla like i did not connect to internet and on my pc settings:

Settings>Devices>Printers> ??? Ricoh is now disappeared either.

While trying to figure out number (1) instructions, number (2) spoiled everything.

I know my post was very long; but i really will be very very very pleasured if you could help me out of this.

Best Regards.

EDİT: Now i can't open my own uploaded png, I got an error: "i.stack.imgur.com refused connection".I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As i couldn't get out of the situation, i have reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and my applications very carefully.Finally, i have no unstable situation and i managed my printer work ;)

So steps in previous topics are clearly correct:

[Ricoh SP111 printer setup help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641405/ricoh-sp111-printer-setup-help)

Except something i need to mention is the file "pstoricohddst-gdi" has to be in following settings:

- Owner: Root
- Accessibility: Read and Write
- Group: Root
- Accessibility: Read
- Others
- Accessibility: Read
- Run: Let the file run just like an executable file.

I hope these settings help for people who face the same problem in the future, i hope not.Additionally, you can see your proceed via CUPS interface as status:
http://localhost:631/printers/

Best Regards.